# NTP for esp8266 v. 4 platform

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, ntp, platformio, esp8266wifi

Updated Espressif 8266 to 4.0.1 (platform.io), getting time from NTP stopped working on all esp8266/32s. Silently assumes 1970s. Seemingly ignores `configTime(MYTZ, "pool.ntp.org", "google.time.com", "time.cloudflare.com");` in time.h code variant.

Tried **time.h** (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/esp8266/examples/NTP-TZ-DST/NTP-TZ-DST.ino)
And **NTPClient.h**
(arduino-libraries/NTPClient@^3.2.1)

Google is spammed by copy pasted examples around those two.

Is there a working for the setup example?

Comment: did you wait until it retrieves the time from the NTP server?

Comment: Yes, synchronously, asynchronously - time wasn't changed, something like this
``` 
do
    {
      time(&now);
      localtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(200);
    } while (((millis() - start) <= (1000U * sec)) && (timeinfo.tm_year < (2016 - 1900)));
    if (timeinfo.tm_year <= (2016 - 1900))
      return false;{}
``` Please, take a note, that code was the same, just stopped working after update platform and libs to the latest versions. Also - see the examples, all of them have the waiting.